# Why we should treat respect, honour, name and fame as dung and poison?

Tags: philosophy, swami

I have some confusion in  Swami Sivananda  book **"How to get Vairagya"**

In his book this statement mention that

**You should treat respect, honour, name and fame as dung and poison**

Why we should treat respect, honour, name and fame as dung and poison?

**My thinking** : If a person get a name and fame , then person become happy because every body will love and respect u.
Evrybody will value ur talk and everybody will follow u.

Name and fame are not easy to get its. Its is very difficult to get name and fame

If a person doesn't get a name and fame.People will not listen ur word and people will not follow u and people will not believe  what u say .

I thinks we should treat name and fame as very  a important role in our life. we should be focus on name and fame then only we get respect from other.If we get respect from other that mean we are getting respect from God. People respect are similar to God respect

Comment: there are different levels of spirituality. 1st level - do good things for the sake of money. 2nd level - do good things for the sake of fame. 3rd level - do good things just for the sake of doing good things. you cannot go directly from level 0 to level 3. go step by step.

Comment: Is is because name and fame are no requirements to go the house of god.

Comment: You are mixing up lot of concepts like a book on Vairagya,name,fame,god,people etc.,Name and Fame from the society are part of Grihasta Ashram/Parvriti path, while Vairagya is part of Sanyas Ashram/Nivriti path. "People respect are similar to God respect."People are basically children of God,whose praise do you desire and is of utmost value?Ignorant Children or adult Father?Children are not aware what is right or wrong,similarly society will praise you for being rich even though your wealth is earned from wrong doings,but the true praise is from the father, the creator who is epitome of Dharma

Comment: okss thanks u for clarification, i was thinking that  People voice mean God voice @ManuKumar

Comment: People are children of God. There are good and bad children, and there praises or judgements can't and shouldn't be taken seriously. God's voice come out of enlightened beings and your own higher inner Self, not from outside masses randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to explain in terms to Bhakti Yoga, from
Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's, Siksastakam -4, which is quite similar.

na dhanaṁ na janaṁ na sundarīṁ
kavitāṁ vā jagad-īśa kāmaye
mama janmani janmanīśvare
bhavatād bhaktir ahaitukī tvayi

"O Almighty Lord, I have no desire to accumulate wealth, nor to enjoy beautiful women. Nor do I want any number of followers. What I want only is the causeless mercy of Your devotional service in my life, birth after birth."

If the  bhakti sådhaka does not give up all connection with the sensual happiness(name, fame, glory etc) of this material world, his pure spiritual form will not arise. For awakening of a sadhakas real spiritual identity in bhakti, whose essence is spiritual sat, chit, and ananda,  the pure character of sådhana-bhakti in its real form   is being clearly described by *negative indication*
na dhanam na janam, etc.
The positive indication refers to  the intrinsic characteristic of bhakti.
In defining the goal of Sadhana the  svarüpa-lakshana refers to those characteristics which are part of its fundamental nature (svarüpa) to be attained. The intrinsic characteristic of  bhakti is that it involves the cultivation of activities favourable to Bhagavan Krishna.
The negative indication refers to characteristics unfavorable of  bhakti.Therefore name, fame, glory is unfavorable.

vairāgya-vidyā-nija-bhakti-yoga-
śikṣārtham ekaḥ puruṣaḥ purāṇaḥ

Vairāgya-vidyā and bhakti-yoga are parallel lines. One is essential for understanding the other.